# Database vendor Code : 8114 while running a report on target machine

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports

My c# application works fine and every reports are working fine in developed machine. While I am trying to run the program on a target machine on of my report shows an error : Failed to retrieve data from the database. Error in File pay_with_bl. (pay_with_bl is my report name). This report contains five parameters. fromDate,toDate,and acc_name for one table and data, ac_name parameter for another table. This report created using sql commands. THere are two commands

```
crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = stDate.Text;
crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["fromDate"];
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;
crParameterValues.Clear();
crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);
```

this is the way i am passing the value to parameter in my form coding. This is working on my machine. Cannot run this report on target machines. I don't no what is the problem.

Comment: That is an error with one of the date values

Comment: @AlexK. I tried with datetimepicker bt its working on my machine and target machine shows the error. And used a text box same problem. How to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error but I resolved it by casting my date value to a specific format. The issue has to do with the date parameter. Kindly see below for the approach I used to resolve mine. Best.

```
crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dateToday.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["@Date"];
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;
```

Comment: In your case, you may do something like crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = convert.ToDateTime(stDate.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");